# almost the same functions behave differently on an $interval loop

Tags: angularjs, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy, cordova-plugins, setinterval

I'm building an app using Cordova that uses the `ng-cordova-bluetoothle` library found [here](https://github.com/randdusing/ng-cordova-bluetoothle).

I'm having two basic functions:

```
function isRunning(){

    return bleReadisRunning()
    .then (function(response){
        response = atob(response.value);
        debugWrite("Response@isRunning: " + response + "\n");
        if(response.status){
            // Do nothing
        } else{
            // Stop the loop
        }
        return response;
    })
    .catch( function(error){
        console.log("isRunning");
    });
}

function getTemp(){
    return bleReadgetTemp()
    .then (function(response){
        response = atob(response.value);
        debugWrite("Response@getTemp: " + response + "\n");
        if(response.status){
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            // Stop the loop :p
        }
        return response;
    })
    .catch( function(error){
        console.log("getTemp");
    })
}
```

What I tried to do was to execute these two functions continuously with a specific interval time. For that reason, I used the  `$interval` service from angularJS and wrote the following code.

```
    vm.startExperimentLoop = function() {
       vm.myCall = $interval( loop, 5000);        
    };


    vm.apiStop = function(){
        $interval.cancel(vm.myCall);
    }
```

Firstly I tried to use only the `isRunning()` within the `loop()` function such as:

```
function loop(){
    isRunning();
}
```

After testing this, everything worked as expected. The call of the `isRunning()` happened each 5seconds. But if I change the `loop()` function and make it run the `getTemp()`, it seems that this interval of 5sec doesn't hold up and the `getTemp()` is called continuously.

Here also are the `bleReadisRinning()` and `bleReadgetTemp()` functions.

```
     function bleReadisRunning(){
        var service_id = '12ab';
        var characteristic_id = '32cd';

        var params = {
            address: $stateParams.address,
            service: service_id,
            characteristic: characteristic_id,
        };

        return $cordovaBluetoothLE.read(params);
     }

     function bleReadgetTemp(){
        var service_id = '12ab';
        var characteristic_id = '31cd';

        var params = {
            address: $stateParams.address,
            service: service_id,
            characteristic: characteristic_id,
        };

        return $cordovaBluetoothLE.read(params);
     }
```

The code to me seems almost the same and I cannot understand where the problem could lie.

P.S: I don't know if that helps but I'm using the `nodeJS` and `bleno` library to setup my peripheral device. Bellow is the way I'm setting up the two characteristics but again, I cannot find any big difference that could explain the issue with the `$interval`.

```
            // IS RUNNING CHARACTERISTIC
            new bleno.Characteristic({
             value: null,
             uuid: settings.is_running_characteristic_id,
             properties: ['read'],
             onReadRequest: function(offset, callback){
                isExperimentRunning()
                .then( (res) => {
                    var buffer = Buffer.from( JSON.stringify(res) );
                    callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, buffer);
                })
             }
           }),
           // GET TEMP CHARACTERISTIC
           new bleno.Characteristic({
               value:null,
               uuid: settings.get_temp_characteristic_id,
               properties: ['read'],
               onReadRequest: function(offset, callback){
                   getTemp()
                   .then( (res) => {
                       var buffer = Buffer.from( JSON.stringify(res) );
                       callback(this.RESULT_SUCCESS, buffer);
                   })
               }
           })
```

**EDIT:**

I found something but not sure why is this happening.

So in the nodeJS side in function `getTemp()` which is onReadRequest, if the response (`res`) is an object with only one attribute, e.g `{'status':'ok'}` , then everything is working as expected, if I put one more attribute to that object e.g `{'status':'ok', 'temp':23}` then the whole process fall apart.

**EDIT.2:**

So it seems that is a matter of size. Either with one attribute in the object it will crash if the size of the object is bigger than this `{'temp':2455555555}`. If I put one more 5 in the value it will do its madness.